# Netbeans debugging error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.xni.XNIException

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Netbeans 7.4 with Apache Tomcat to debug a servlet.

The Tomcat server is throwing an error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.xni.XNIException

I'm new to the Java thing, and I was asked to make changes to this app, but I can't get it to debug because of this error.

When I Google it, it shows as a bug in Netbeans, but I cannot find help on fixing the bug.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I guess you're referring to this. https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232690

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to this.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232690

The bug history says this bug was fixed somewhere in July 2013.
I would try using the latest IDE version or pull a nightly build 
(in which this bug's fix was reported as being available).

Then if you still see the bus is not fixed, you may want to contact the
Netbeans team providing all the details (which build you tested it 
with, on which OS, how you reproduced the bug, etc.)